# Can I use Cat6 ethernet cable to connect switches to Fibaro binary sensors

Tags: switches, low-power

The Fibaro binary sensor ( https://manuals.fibaro.com/binary-sensor ) is capable to handle two potential-free inputs and is powered by 9-30V DC.

Can I use Cat6 ethernet cable from four double switches to connect to two Fibaro binary sensors? I would use all the four pairs of wires to connect the devices. The cable runs inside the wall but not in a tube.

Ps: Unfortunately there is no neutral 230V behind the switch and it would be hard to have one, but for historical reasons ethernet cables are run there.

Comment: Which spec are you unsure that it might not meet? Voltage, current earth grounding?  wireless path loss?

Comment: Well, almost all. But mostly the signal loss  and the warmth inside the wall...

Comment: I don't see any heat rise from the signals to be concerned about and RF path loss depends on many sources of reflection.  Test outside the walls 1st if possible or not just try it and report back if any errors or not and cable length

Comment: Thanks... one more. Shall I use the lowest possible voltage, 9V? I cannot try outside yet, as I was not sure it is feasible, so I did not buy the binary sensor. But according to the info you give, i should give it a try.

Comment: I think 12Vdc is more common .

Answer (score 0):

Cat6 is good for low-frequency signals too and especially with properly grounded shields using a 1nF cap to earth ground to shield termination prevent line ground loop noise if present.

RC snubbers can also improve signal noise rejection.

Interference near Triac dimmers or brushed motors are typical issues on long cables.
Ethernet cards use Common mode chokes and isolation transformer to improve signals.

Cat6 cables have designated pairs, so use those. Using parallel wires may extend the useful length due to lower inductance since this is high impedance and may improve signal integrity.

I think the 1 wire communication is rated for 30m if there is no extreme interference. Even then, a 330 Ohm + 0.01uF series snubber across the analog signal can suppress this noise.

The datasheet says...

> Do not connect other sensors than DS18B20 to the 1-wire line (terminals TP and TD).
>   It is prohibited to connect the TP and TD lines to devices that are not compatible with the 1-wire protocol. Unused lines should be left insulated.
>   Use conductors made from a single wire with a length of up to 30 meters in order to connect the DS18B20 sensors